# Редактирование свойств выбранного объекта

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе есть возможность редактировать свойства выбранного объекта.

Это реализовано через свойство *SelectedObject* во ViewModel.

Проблема в следующем. Если я выбираю объект, редактирую его свойства и кликаю в пределах текущего `TabItem`, то свойство обновляется. Но если же я редактирую свойство и, не убирая курсор с текстового поля, переключаюсь на другую вкладку, то изменения в свойстве не сохраняются.

Установка `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` в моем случае не подходит. Нужен именно `LostFocus`.

Как это пофиксить?

---

Набросал пример, который отражает проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Code-behind:

```
public class PersonVm : BaseVm
{
    private string _name;
    private string _lastname;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Lastname
    {
        get => _lastname;
        set
        {
            _lastname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}


public class MainVm : BaseVm
{
    private PersonVm _selectedPerson;

    public MainVm()
    {
        Class1.Add(new PersonVm { Name = "Алексей", Lastname = "Алексеев" });
        Class1.Add(new PersonVm { Name = "Иван", Lastname = "Иванов" });

        Class2.Add(new PersonVm { Name = "Петр ", Lastname = "Петров" });
        Class2.Add(new PersonVm { Name = "Николай", Lastname = "Николаев" });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<PersonVm> Class1 { get; } = new ObservableCollection<PersonVm>();
    public ObservableCollection<PersonVm> Class2 { get; } = new ObservableCollection<PersonVm>();

    public PersonVm SelectedPerson
    {
        get => _selectedPerson;
        set
        {
            _selectedPerson = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedPerson}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lastname}" 
                                   Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Class1" 
                 Content="{Binding Class1}"
                 ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" />

        <TabItem Header="Class2" 
                 Content="{Binding Class2}"
                 ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" />
    </TabControl>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Имя" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Фамилия" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Lastname}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: А если вместо TabControl использовать что-то другое?

Comment: @Андрей, Другой компонент со вкладками? В моем проекте используется [Dragablz](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz) это не решает проблему.

Comment: Ну а галочку-то на ответе поставите? Или он вас не до конца устроил? Задавайте вопросы, будем думать :)

Comment: @Андрей, Все устроило и все понятно. Извините, про галочку забыл :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На данный момент получается, что при возникновении события `LostFocus` привязки уже нет, поэтому она не срабатывает. Из всех `PreviewXXX`-событий у `TextBox` есть только `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus`, если подписаться на него и посмотреть отладчиком что лежит в `Text`, то мы увидим, что в нем привязка пока еще есть, значит это событие нам подойдет.

Действительно, давайте попробуем в подписчике принудительно обновить привязку, добавьте в обработчик такой код:

```
(sender as TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

и вы увидите, что все работает как вы и хотели.

Что можно с этим сделать? Можно, например, добавить обработчик события для всех нужных `TextBox`, или реализовать наследника `TextBox` с таким поведением, ну или, наконец, сделать `Attached Behavior`.

Первый вариант, я считаю, плох, т.к. нужно будет добавлять обработчики такие во всех окнах/контролах где нам нужен `TextBox` с таким поведением, ну и если вдруг для какого-то из `TextBox` нам понадобится еще один обработчик этого события - его придется вешать из кода.

Поэтому я покажу последние два варианта.

Наследник `TextBox`, все предельно просто, я создал такой класс:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(e);
        GetBindingExpression(TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Всё. Это уже работает, достаточно вместо стандартного `TextBox` использовать `local:MyTextBox`. Но у этого подхода есть минус - если вы стилизуете стандартные `TextBox`, то эти кастомные штатно не будут подхватывать стили и их придется стилизовать отдельно, хотя, по сути, у нас тот же самый `TextBox`.

Поэтому наиболее оптимальным решением видится сделать прикрепляемое поведение.

Подключите к проекту сборку `System.Windows.Interactivity` и создайте класс:

```
class TextBoxLostFocusUpdateBindingBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus += OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus -= OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus;
    }

    private void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Теперь в XAML добавьте пространство имен: `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

И у нужных `TextBox` укажите это поведение:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Lastname}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:TextBoxLostFocusUpdateBindingBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

PS.: Что примечательно, технология `Binding` в `WPF` достаточно интеллектуальна для того, чтобы не обновлять одну и ту же привязку, если с момента прошлого обновления изменений не было. Поэтому нам не нужно предпринимать никаких дополнительных действий чтобы отключить обновление привязки по `LostFocus`, она просто не будет никогда там обновляться, обновление теперь будет происходить всегда по `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus`