# Изменение TextBox, при переключении между TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть TabControl, с несколькими TabItem. В них есть TextBox, которые забинжены на одну и ту же переменную. Мне нужно, чтобы при переключении между TabItem, эти Text в TextBox стирался.

Comment: Как понять это *В них есть TextBox, которые забинжены на одну и ту же переменную*?,и добавьте ваши старание к вопросу и опишите боллее подробно вашу проблему так то мне не очень понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключите библиотеку System.Windows.Interactivity как написано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726434/218063) и ознакомьтесь с [этим топиком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710739/218063) (вопросом и ответом).

Теперь всё просто, ViewModel:

```
class MainVm : Vm
{
    string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set => Set(ref text, value);
    }

    public DelegateCommand ClearTextCommand { get; }

    public MainVm()
    {
        ClearTextCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => Text = "");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<TabControl>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClearTextCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <c:TextBoxLostFocusUpdateBindingBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <c:TextBoxLostFocusUpdateBindingBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Если же аббревиатура MVVM для вас ничего не значит, то вы можете просто подписаться на `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` ваших `TextBox`ов и обновлять привязку в подписчике (это описано в вышеуказанном ответе). Затем подписаться на `SelectionChanged` `TabControl`а, и в подписчике просто очищать свойство, привязанное к `TextBox`ам.