# С# WPF биндинг события

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Как можно биндить события подобно биндингу Command? Например double click можно забиндить таким образом чтобы в View Model узнать на что был собственно double click?

Comment: С помощью `EventTrigger` из `System.Windows.Interactivity`. Пример здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/825927/218063 Но, возможно, более правильно через MouseBinding: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735522/218063

Comment: Получилось сделать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, по моим наблюдениям это не очень благодарный участник)

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, спасибо