# Как сохранять состояние контролов при смене табов в TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

В DataTemplate для таба есть TextBox. Но при смене таба набранный текст в нем сбрасывается на пустой. Как исправить?

```
public class TabItem1
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
}

public class TabItem2
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> Tabs { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<object>
        {
            new TabItem1 {Header = "One"},
            new TabItem2 {Header = "Two"}
        };
    }
}

public class Selector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is TabItem1)
        {
            return MainWindow.FindResource("Template1") as DataTemplate;
        }

        if (item is TabItem2)
        {
            return MainWindow.FindResource("Template2") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfTabTemplate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTabTemplate"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Selector x:Key="Selector"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
            <TextBox/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
            <TextBox/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <TabControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource Selector}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Потому что TabItem не существует, когда он скрыт, см.: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/943427/218063 Храните данные в VM

Comment: Кстати, почему у вас в VM контролы?

Comment: У меня вопрос, у вас разве вызывается FindResource()? Вроде же надо создать экземпляр

Comment: Не очень понял про хранение данных в VM. В момент закрытия таба TextBox шлет тогда пустой текст в VM.

Comment: Тут еще засада в том, что в моем UserControl есть свойства, про которые VM не знает, т.е. исключительно для отображения, к логике отношения не имеющие. Выносить их в модель - неправильно. Пока вижу единственным вариантом использовать наследник TabContol без виртуализации, который гуглится.

Comment: По поводу того, что TextBox шлет пустой текст в VM: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711393/218063